# Vue how to set the active tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue tab component that console logs out the correct index of the selected tab but I don't know how to set the active tab so it is opened. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Component:

```
<Tabs
  :tabs="tabs"
  :active-tab-index="activeTab"
  @tab-changed="changeTab"
/>
```

Markup

```
<div v-show="activeTab === 0">
Show tab one content
</div>

<div v-show="activeTab === 1">
Show tab two content
</div>
```

Data:

```
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [
        { id: 0, name: 'Tab One' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Tab Two' },
      ],
      activeTab: 0,
    }
  },
```

Method:

```
changeTab(index) {
  console.log('Change activeTab', index)
},
```

Comment: You can use dynamic component property to implement  tabs in vue [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not completely clear to me where the method and data is, but I assume it's in the parent, so in that case you'd simply need to change the function to something like this:

```js
changeTab(index) {
  this.activeTab = index
},
```

your component could be even cleaner if it would provide option to use v-model on it like: `v-model:activeTabIndex="activeTab"`. To make this happen you'd just need to emit the data inside the component with `update:activeTabIndex` instead of `tab-changed`.